# Looking for a QProgressDialog with 2 (or more) progress bars

Tags: qt, widget

I could do with a progress dialog that has 2 progress bars on it.

In my app my users are able to select several files at the same time for processing. Process the file often takes tens of seconds.

I currently use a QProgressDialog to show the progress of a single file processing.  I show this at the start of each file, but it looks horrible as it closes and opens again for each file - and there is no indication of overall progress.

Does such a thing exist within the Qt framework?  (I couldn't find one)
Am I going to have to make one myself?

Comment: You'll have to make one yourself

Comment: What prevents you from creating a custom dialog?

Comment: @mhcuervo - nothing, but time and experience (ie lack of).  And its better to not re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Thanks @FrankOsterfeld.  I suspected that might be the case.  One of the nice things about the standard QProgressDialog is its ability to decide whether to display or not.